# Discord.js v14 >2+ Minutes Express Request/Response Time(s)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, discord.js

Essentially, I have a separate third party sending Requests to my App. They are received everything works except embed updating & slow response time(s). Takes up to 2 minutes to receive a request, and embeds do not update as they go through the functions.

```
// init project
const redis = require('redis');
const express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const https = require('https');
const app = express();
const { Client, EmbedBuilder, GatewayIntentBits, Guild } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent] });
const redClient = redis.createClient();

//// IMPORTANT VVV
let token = 'token'; //process.env.SECRET //Your token goes in key.env (Discord bot)
let prefix = '!'; // Discord bot prefix
let rolename = 'Admin'; //"rolenamehere"
/// IMPORTANT ^^^

let numbers = [
    "0️⃣",
    "1️⃣",
    "2️⃣",
    "3️⃣",
    "4️⃣"
]

async function startApp() {
    var promise = client.login(token)
    console.log("Starting...");
    promise.catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Discord bot login | " + error);
        process.exit(1);
    });
}
startApp();
client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Successfully logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
})

const Invalid = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor('#eb4034')
    .setDescription("Invalid user")

const footer = {
    text: '(forked by corehimself)'
};


var toBan = [];
function byUID(method,usr,message) {
    const Emb = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor('#fff200')
        //.setTitle(request.headers.username + "'s Data")
        // .setTitle("Attempt")
        //.setAuthor('Roblox Error','')
        .setDescription("Attempting to "+method+" UserID "+ usr +"...")
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter(footer);

    message.edit({ embeds: [Emb] });
    https.get("https://api.roblox.com/users/" + usr, (res) => {
        
        let data = '';
        res.on('data', d => {
        data += d
        })
        res.on('end', () => {
        if (res.statusCode == 200) {
            toBan.push({method: method,username: JSON.parse(data).Username,value: usr,cid: message.channel.id,mid: message.id});
        } else {
            message.edit({ embeds: [Invalid] });
        }
        });
    }).on('error', error => {
        console.error("RBLX API (UID) | " + error);
    });
}

function byUser(method,usr,message) {
    const Emb = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor('#fff200')
        //.setTitle(request.headers.username + "'s Data")
        // .setTitle("Attempt")
        //.setAuthor('Roblox Error','')
        .setDescription("Attempting to "+method+" username "+ usr +"...")
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter(footer);
    message.edit({ embeds: [Emb] });
    https.get("https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username?username=" + usr, (res) => {
        let data = '';
        res.on('data', d => {
            data += d
            console.log(`Data: ${data}`)
        })
        res.on('end', () => {
            if (JSON.parse(data).Id != undefined) {
                console.log("push")
                toBan.push({method: method,value: JSON.parse(data).Id,username: JSON.parse(data).Username,cid: message.channel.id,mid: message.id});
            } else {
                message.edit({ embeds: [Invalid] });
            }
        });
    }).on('error', error => {
        console.error("RBLX API (Username) | " + error);
    });
}

function isCommand(command, message) {
    var command = command.toLowerCase();
    var content = message.content.toLowerCase();
    return content.startsWith(prefix + command);
}

const TookTooLong = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor('#eb4034')
    .setDescription("You took too long to respond!")


async function determineType(method, message, BotMsg, args) {
    if (isNaN(Number(args[1]))) {
        byUser(method,args[1],BotMsg);
    } else {
        const Emb = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor('#ea00ff')
            //.setTitle(request.headers.username + "'s Data")
            .setTitle("Is this a UserID or a Username?")
            //.setAuthor('Roblox Error','')
            .setDescription("Please react with the number that matches the answer.")
            .addField(numbers[0] + ": Username","This is a players username in game.")
            .addField(numbers[1] + ": UserID","This is the players UserId connect with the account.")
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter(footer);
        BotMsg.edit({ embeds: [Emb] });
        try {
            await BotMsg.react(numbers[0]);
            await BotMsg.react(numbers[1]);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('One of the emojis failed to react.');
        }
        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return numbers.includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
        };
        BotMsg.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time'] })
        .then(collected => {
            const reaction = collected.first();
            const ind = numbers.findIndex(function(n){
                return n == reaction.emoji.name;
            })
            BotMsg.reactions.removeAll().catch(error => console.error('Failed to remove reactions: ', error));
            if (ind == 0) {
                byUser(method, args[1], BotMsg);
            } else if (ind == 1) {
                byUID(method, args[1], BotMsg);
            }
        })
        .catch(collected => {
            BotMsg.reactions.removeAll().catch(error => console.error('Failed to remove reactions: ', error));
            BotMsg.edit({ embeds: [TookTooLong] });
        });
    }
}  

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;

    if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === rolename)) {
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
        var Emb = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor('#eb4034')
            .setDescription("Working...")

        if (isCommand("Ban", message)) {
            var BotMsg = await message.reply({ embeds: [Emb] });
            determineType("Ban", message, BotMsg, args);
        } else if (isCommand("Unban", message)) {
            var BotMsg = await message.reply({ embeds: [Emb] });
            determineType("Unban", message, BotMsg, args);
        } else if (isCommand("Kick",message)) {
            var BotMsg = await message.reply({ embeds: [Emb] });
            determineType("Kick", message, BotMsg, args);
        }
    }
});
//
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', async function(request, response) {
    if (request.headers.username != undefined) { 
      const key = request.headers.cid + '_' + request.headers.mid;
      redClient.get(key, async (err, cachedResponse) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
  
        if (cachedResponse) {
          console.log('Cache hit');
          response.send(JSON.parse(cachedResponse));
        } else {
          console.log('Cache miss');
          const channel = await client.channels.cache.get(request.headers.cid);
          channel.messages.fetch(request.headers.mid)
            .then(msg => {
              if (request.headers.rblxerror == undefined) {
                const Emb = new EmbedBuilder()
                      .setColor('#00ff44')
                      .setTitle(request.headers.method + " successful. ")
                      .addFields({name: 'Username', value: request.headers.username})
                      .addFields({name: 'UserID', value: request.headers.value})
                      .setTimestamp()
                      .setFooter(footer);
                if (msg.author != undefined) {
                  msg.edit({ embeds: [Emb] });
                } else {
                  channel.send({ embeds: [Emb] });
                }
                client.setex(key, 3600, JSON.stringify(toBan[0]));
                response.send(toBan[0]);
                toBan.shift();
              } else {
                const Emb = new EmbedBuilder()
                      .setColor('#eb4034')
                      .setTitle(request.headers.method + " failed. ")
                      .addFields({name: 'Username', value: request.headers.username})
                      .addFields({name: 'UserID', value: request.headers.value})
                      .addFields({name: 'Rblx-Error', value: request.headers.rblxerror})
                      .setTimestamp()
                      .setFooter(footer);
                if (msg.author != undefined) {
                    msg.edit({ embeds: [Emb] });
                } else {
                    channel.send({ embeds: [Emb] });
                }
                response.send(false);
              }
          })
          .catch( err =>{
            console.log(err);       
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log("returned");
      response.send(false);
    }
  });

// listen for requests & Keep bot alive

let listener = app.listen(8000, function() {
    //setInterval(() => { // Used to work sometime ago
    //    http.get(`http://${process.env.PROJECT_DOMAIN}.glitch.me/`);
    //}, 280000);
    console.log('Not that it matters but your app is listening on port ' + listener.address().port);
});

client.on('error', console.error)
```

I have tried adding redis, I've read that it enables cache to speed up response/req times, however no luck.

Comment: Do you receive any errors? E.g. `channel.send(Emb)` should definitely throw an error as it should be `channel.send({ embeds: [Emb] })`

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I've fixed that as well, forgot to update this version. Will update that quickly.

Comment: However no errors.